# Memory leaks icCube 6.8.5

Tags: iccube

After a few days we experience severe memory leaks that effectively halts our icCube server. We have only 4 schemas with estimated memory usage of 1551MB, 878MB, 1017KB and 1284MB. We have 72GB physical memory. The last memory message in the log is:

> free:5184MB / total:120GB / max:120G

After restart and some hour and half the memory usage is a lot less:

> free:34.3GB / total:50.0GB / max:120GB

We are using icCube 6.8.5. This is our memory setting: `-Xms50G -Xmx120G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500`

Please advice.

Comment: you can contact icCube at support at iccube dot com

Answer (score 0):

Java used as much memory as it can, it's going to expand even though it could work with a lot less space. So in order to know if it's a memory leak or not could you run several times the GC from the management user interface ?

in the GWT version :

[image]

In the beta Material UI ( .../icCube/console/admin/ServerStatus ):

[image]

If you still are using too much memory , please contact icCube support, looks like a leak issue.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't help. We will contact support.